# Pylint ungrouped-imports warning

Tags: python, pylint

In my python script - youdao.py, in order to be compatible with python2 and python3, I import urlopen like this style:

```
try:
    # compatible for python2
    from urllib import urlencode
    from urllib2 import urlopen
except ImportError:
    # compatible for python3
    from urllib.parse import urlencode
    from urllib.request import urlopen
```

See details in https://github.com/MintCN/youdao-python/blob/master/youdao_simple/youdao.py#L22

When you use `pylint youdao.py`, you will see `ungrouped-imports warning`, how do I modify code to remove this warning?

Answer (score 29):

I had similar issue. Pylint prefers grouping of packages.

CASE 1: Causes ungrouped-imports warning

```
import keras
import sklearn

from keras import losses
from sklearn import svm
```

CASE 2: [No Warning]

```
import keras
from keras import losses

import sklearn
from sklearn import svm
```

Comment: Please have a look at my python code. There is not single "import" statement. You mean I need to add two "import" statements before "from ... import ...", right?

Comment: Then it will give unused import, instead what python expects is reordering them together. In this case `from urllib2 import urlopen` can be written above `urlib import`

Comment: This is unbelievably incredible :)

Answer (score 5):

```
try:
    # compatible for python2
    # from urllib import urlencode
    from urllib2 import urlopen
    from urllib import urlencode
except ImportError:
    # compatible for python3
    from urllib.parse import urlencode
    from urllib.request import urlopen
```

This fixes it -- all urllib imports should appear uninterrupted; otherwise pylint complains.

Comment: Did you write anything different than OP

Comment: As a matter of fact, there is a "2"  in `from urllib2 import urlopen` instead of  `from urllib import urlencode`. Admittedly it took myself a while to locate it. The question and hence my answer is probably moot since not too many people still use Python2?

Comment: Understood, we need grouping of urllib together. Then it resolves. So all similar package imports come together, like reordering them together. You can add may be another line to clarify. Uninterrupted had me quizzed.